# java scanner exception maybe the data is to big？

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I did not get an error when I input a few thousand data, but when the number of data changed to 100000, I got an error 'Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException'. I'm not sure if it is a problem with Scanner. Can anyone help me with this issue?"

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;

class Work {
    public long end;
    public long money;
    Work(long end, long money){
        this.end = end;
        this.money = money;
    }
}
public class TanXin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        List<Work> works = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            long end = scanner.nextLong();
            long money = scanner.nextLong();
            works.add(new Work(end ,money));
        }
        Collections.sort(works, new Comparator<Work>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Work o1, Work o2) {
                return Long.compare(o1.end, o2.end);
            }
        });
        scanner.nextLine();
        long curEnd =  works.get(0).end;
        long money = works.get(0).money;
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < works.size(); i++) {
            Work work = works.get(i);
            if(work.end == curEnd){
                money = Math.max(money, work.money);
            }
            else {
                result=result.add(BigInteger.valueOf(money));
                money = work.money;
                curEnd = work.end;
            }
        }
        result=result.add(BigInteger.valueOf(money));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

my input is similar to this:

100000
801615855 349230664
887145852 256709348
543490607 406712523
290306792 866994656
761434274 614622174
523543132 477488683
416651127 515580101
610336950 152185241
337713494 547698342
6453239 251894056
17161871 278487265
309123183 826630026
22171935 97670396
937046566 551871611
338360787 511206428
234499030 12274630
999066863 377262036
498450141 907352279
699130053 40056368
341503872 598356413
92329093 58969313
839293680 912223354
435852220 370051435
328226392 703616380
84394712 320189993
89139302 692379179
668921100 37915667
750500527 980565603
951214595 443240740
342283327 733767608
674959282 407118651
114057416 595985258
908001458 748864346
406064066 170499053

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire error message.

Comment: Googling "java int max value" shows that an `int` can store any number up to `2147483647`, so `100000` definitely is not too big.

Comment: When there are thousands of data, I can press enter and get the results. But when there are 100,000 data, I noticed that pressing enter does not end the input.

Comment: That simply means there is a 'number' that is either [A] too large for `nextLong()`, or [B] some non-digit in your input. And that input is somewhere deep down into the data. If you are asking: "Is java, a tool used by many millions, randomly broken for no good reason" the answer is virtually always: No. Stop blaming the tools, start taking the messages on face value: There is a non-long in there. Don't make it more complicated.

Comment: If truly this was too much data, you'd get an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: As the comment from @Code-Apprentice said,  please edit the question to include the entire error message. Include the stack trace, because that will point to a specific call sequence, showing line numbers. That can be used to point to the line in your code that triggered the exception.

Comment: By any chance, when you enter `100000` is that exactly what you enter? Or do you enter something like `100,000` ?

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. For example, you can add `System.out.println()` calls to print values of variables. This will help you see the values that are ok up until the program crashes on the problem. Then find the last of those values in your input data to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: More likely there is an error in the data, causing your scanner to be unable to process a value as a `long`. Try changing `nextLong()` to `next()` to read 2 `String`  Objects. Use `Long.parseLong (String str)` to get the `long` values. Put the `for` loop block inside a `try` block and add catch `(NumberFormatException ex)` block, where you display the values of `n` and the two input strings.

Comment: How are you entering 100000 pairs of numbers from stdin (i.e., from the console or System.in) ?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer yes，i enter it by System in

Comment: You type 200,000 numbers by hand?

Comment: That many data items should be in a file. There's a good chance of making a typing error. Try using a `Scanner` to wrap something that reads from a file instead of `System.in`.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer i copy the data

Comment: Perhaps you have an odd number of numbers in your input.

Comment: Even so, you can make a mistake using copy-and-paste. Try altering the program to read from a file. An alternative is to add the count (100000 or other value) to the top of the file, and have your program process it using stdin redirection.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I knew the reason. If you read a large amount of data into memory at once, it may cause memory overflow, and the program may get stuck in the data reading stage because the operating system cannot allocate enough memory for the program, resulting in program hang or crash. In this case, you can try to use buffered reading or external sorting methods to alleviate memory pressure.

Comment: As true as that may be, memory overflow should not cause a `java.util.InputMismatchException`. If it does, you may have uncovered a Java bug. It might be a good idea to report it.